# A form in opportunities object

Tags: form

I need your help. My company asked me to implement a **FORM** in the opportunities object (better if it were implemented in the opportunity builder). The idea is that sales-representatives fill out 5 questions in that form that are related to the process of that opportunity. This data would help us to get the probability of won that opportunity beetween others.
The first approach I can think of is with Visualforce. But I wonder is there are not other posibilities to achieve this since we just have **Professional Edition** in our Company.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning Flow (which includes screen elements to capture data) is available in Professional Edition

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_builder.htm&type=5

You could hook up the flow to a quick action button on the Opportunity detail page or look at other ways to [distribute the flow via Trailhead course](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/screen_flow_distribution)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! A lot of thanks for your help!

Comment: @serranomorante - as a service to the community, if this answers works for you; mark it as accepted.  But no worries if you're looking for a better answer :-)